# Ternary operator for rows without using state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with a dynamic number of rows. Within each row I have two cells. When the row is in the initial state, only the first cell is showing. When the row is clicked, both cells will show. I know how to do this with a static element and using state, but I am not sure how best to structure this table.

```
<tbody>
{invAdd.map(add =>
  <tr key={add.itemName} className="bckgr-white border-1b add-items disp-flex" onClick={this.handleAddClick}>
    <td className="point-none">{add.itemName}</td>
    {if parentNode has class "selected"
      ?
      <td>
      <input className="addit-input" type="text" />
      <select className="select">
      <option value="ABC" />
      <option value="DEF" />
      </select>
      </td>
      :
      null
    }
  </tr>
)}
</tbody>
```

I am not sure how to make this comparison without using state. I tried dynamically generating variables but this did not work either.

Comment: *"When the row is in the initial state, only the first cell is showing. When the row is clicked, both cells will show."* That sounds like state (whether the row's been clicked). Why are you trying to do it without state?

Comment: In the code you have *"if parentNode has class "selected""* -- in that case, you already have state, and can do this with CSS rather than JavaScript: Hide the cell by default, and show it if its parent has `.selected`.

Comment: You probably shouldn't render based on `parentNode has class "selected"`. If you think about it, how will the "selected" class get added to the parent element? My guess, you'd have to set a state property in your click handler, and add "selected" to className based on that. Use the same property to display your second column.

Comment: No it's just a css modification to add the class selected. The reason I don't think I can do it with setting a state is that the number of rows is dynamic. As far as I know it's not possible to dynamically create states for each row.